# It seems there too many activities

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose I have an app that contains information about objects of my city.
I have MainActivity that contains RecyclerView with 7 elements (categories of objects: shops, shop centers...).
By clicking on each item, I get to another Activity that contains another RecyclerView (CardView) with elements (concrete objects of each category).
By clicking on each item, of CardView, I get to another Activity which contains only ViewPager with 3 tabs (description of concrete object).
So I get about 80 activities in my app.
Question: Is it normal to use so many activities or I should somehow reuse activities?

Comment: `is it normal to use so many activities` **NO**. `or I should somehow reuse activities?` **YES**.

Comment: reuse activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sould have 3 activities. The first for categories, the second for CardCiew and the third for the ViewPager.

What you must do is to create general activities that receives different data (of the 3 types you described) and show them.

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity - A ListView of `Category`

CategoryActivity - Displays a concrete `Category`. Now, you could subclass this into many Activities, but try to generalize, if possible.

SubCategoryActivity - Click some element of a `Category` to display a `ViewPager` of elements.

---

I only count 3 Activities here, and the bottom two could be combined into one Activity that cycles Fragments.